# How to create an alias on two indexes with logstash?

Tags: alias, logstash, logstash-grok, elasticsearch

In the cluster that I am working on there are two main indexes, let's say `indexA` and `indexB` but these two indexes are indexed each day so normaly I have `indexA-{+YYYY.MM.dd}` and `indexB-{+YYYY.MM.dd}`.

What I want is to have one alias that gathers `indexA-{+YYYY.MM.dd}` and `indexB-{+YYYY.MM.dd}` together and named `alias-{+YYYY.MM.dd}`.

Does anyone know how to gather two indexes in one alias with logstash ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do it with logstash directly.  You can do it from an external program using the elasticsearch API: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

For example:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "indexA-2015.01.01", "alias" : "alias-2015.01.01" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "indexB-2015.01.01", "alias" : "alias-2015.01.01" } }
    ]
}'
```

The other option (which doesn't meet your requirements of having it named `alias-yyyy.mm.dd`) is to use an index template that automatically adds an alias when the index is created.

See http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/add_alias_template -d '{
  "template" : "index*",
  "aliases" : {
    "alias" : {}
    }
  }
}'
```

This will add the alias of `alias` to every index named `index`*.

You can then do all of your queries against alias.  You can setup that alias in Kibana as an index and things will just work right.